# How to integrate shopify store in Android Native application?

Tags: android, api, wordpress, rest

I have a Shopify store, now i want to create a native application of my store in Android. Is there any REST API's which can give me all store products etc or is there any Shopify library that i can use to connect to my online store. I don't want to use webview. All i need is a native android application with all products on application same as i already have on my Shopify Store.
I was just wondering if shopify provides us API to fetch data or something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The Shopify [Storefront
>   API](https://help.shopify.com/en/api/storefront-api)
>   provides customer-facing access to a shop's data. This enables you to
>   build customer-facing shopping experiences by accessing functionality
>   such as managing a customer's cart, accessing the storefront view of
>   products, and creating checkouts. Storefront API access is not the
>   same as [Admin API](https://help.shopify.com/en/api/reference) access,
>   which is merchant-facing and does not include the same set of
>   permissions.
>
> The Storefront API is composed of the following:
>
> - [Customers](https://help.shopify.com/api/custom-storefronts/storefront-api/reference/object/customer/) - Information about customers in Shopify such as their shipping address and display name.
> - [Nodes](https://help.shopify.com/api/custom-storefronts/storefront-api/reference/object/) - Set of Shopify Storefront API root nodes, including Checkouts, Collections, Orders, Payments, etc. See a complete list of nodes [here](https://help.shopify.com/api/custom-storefronts/storefront-api/reference/object/).
> - [Shops](https://help.shopify.com/api/custom-storefronts/storefront-api/reference/object/shop/) - Shop information such as billing address, currency code, and domain.
>
> The Storefront API is GraphQL-based so you can query the
>   representation of this data by passing in GraphQL queries. You can
>   also make GraphQL [mutations](https://help.shopify.com/api/custom-storefronts/storefront-api/reference/mutation/) to modify data.
>
> Using the Storefront API, you can:
>
> - Fetch data about a single product or a collection of products to display on any website or device.
> - Create unique checkout experiences with full control over the shopping cart.
> - Create new customers or modify existing ones, including address information.
> - Allow customers to select unique product options.
>
> [Android Buy SDK](https://help.shopify.com/en/api/storefront-api/tools/android-buy-sdk) - The Mobile Buy SDK makes it easy to create custom storefronts in your mobile app, where users can buy products using Android Pay or their credit card. The SDK connects to the Shopify platform using GraphQL, and supports a wide range of native storefront experiences.<sup>source [1](https://help.shopify.com/en/api/storefront-api/reference) [2](https://help.shopify.com/en/api/storefront-api/tools/android-buy-sdk)</sup>

Comment: Shopify-buy-sdk vs apollo graphql client, what are the pro and cons? Difficult to find information online